# jQuery Conditional Statement using Int within a div

Tags: jquery, html, integer, conditional-statements

So, my question in it's most basic form:

```
<div id="total"> 0 </div>
```

and what I'm hoping to accomplish with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ("#total" > 2){
    /*do something*/
  }   
});
```

I feel like this should be something relatively easy, but the syntax is escaping me. Any help would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the text of an element, and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get a Number from that:

```
if(parseInt($("#total").text(), 10) > 2) {
    //Do something
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/L32cu/).

Note how the selector (`#total`) is passed into jQuery (`$(selector)`). In your question you have the correct selector, but it's just a string, so your `if` statement would compare the string "#total" to the number 2.

Comment: Oh okay great, thanks so much. I really appreciate the explanation as well. This may be an entirely different question, but if #total goes over 2 at any time, the event should be triggered correct?

Comment: @RobErskine, No, this event will only be triggered if `#total` is greater than 2 on document.ready.

Comment: Thanks Xyan. Is there a way to make it update if the int changes?

Comment: Figured it out - I threw the conditional statement within a mousedown function. Thanks everyone for the help again

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     if (parseInt($.trim(("#total").text()),10) > 2){
         /*do something*/
    }   
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `trim` as `parseInt` doesn't care about spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     if (parseInt($("#total").text()) > 2){
         /*do something*/
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it.

```
if(parseInt($('#total').text()) > 2){
   //do something.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try -

```
if (("#total").val() > 2)
```

Comment: As `#total` is a `div` element it won't have a `value` property which is what `val` returns.

Comment: Won't work for divs. The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`